# Struts2 Loop Once in Nested Iterator

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to loop once inside a nested iterator with struts2 tags. This is what I have so far:

JAVA:

```
private List<Parent> allParent = new ArrayList<Parent>();
private List<Children> allChildren = new ArrayList<Children>();
```

JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="allParent">
  Parent name: <s:property value="parentName"/>
  <s:iterator value="allChildren">
       First child: <s:property value="childName"/>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

If I separate the 2 iterators then all items are listed perfectly. If I nest them then none of the children show. After I get the children to show, I want to limit them so just one shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<s:iterator value="allParent" var="parent">
  Parent name: <s:property value="#parent.parentName"/>
  <s:iterator value="allChildren" var="child">
       First child: <s:property value="#child.childName"/>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

**UPDATE**

If you just want to show one of the child, think about **s:subset**

```
<s:iterator value="allParent" var="parent">
  Parent name: <s:property value="#parent.parentName"/>
  <s:subset source="allChildren" count="what_ever_u_like">
  <s:iterator>
    <s:property />
  </s:iterator>
  </s:subset>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: but how do you make it stop after it's iterated just once?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not working because the jsp is thinking that in `allParent` exists a getter called `getAllChildren` instead of iterating under the list `allChildren` that you have in your action class.

## Possible solution

Join the two lists in one map `Map<Parent, List<Children>> map`. Then, in the jsp page iterate over the map and each value of the map.

```
<s:iterator value="map">
     Parent name: <s:property value="key"/>
     <s:iterator value="value">
         First child: <s:property />
     </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: I'm unable to join the lists into a map for business logic integrity reasons